# Global store: state conflicts

Tags: javascript, vuex, store, pinia

I use Pinia store where I have 4 actions: `loadRecipesByKeyword`, `loadPopularRecipes`, `loadPaginatedRecipes`, `loadRecipesCount`. I've noticed I have data conflicts when I put all of the data in the same state property `data`.

```
const data = await res.json();
this.data = data;
```

For example, let's say I'm at `/home` right now where I load popular recipes. If I go to `/recipes` where I have a pagination and I load limited amount of recipes per page, instead of seeing the limited amount, I see all of the popular recipes loaded for some reason, even though I have a separate query for this task on the server and the store action called `loadPaginatedRecipes`. Something's wrong with the data persistance and there's definitely a conflict.

Should I add all the data into one state like I do right now, but manage it somehow more correctly, or should I separate it into different properties to avoid issues, for example:

```
export const state = () => {
     return {
         popularRecipes: [],
         recipeByKeyword: [],
         paginatedRecipes: [],
         reсipesCount: 0,
         selectedRecipe: null,
     };
};
```

Please, give a solution.

Comment: everything mentioned related to your code should be included in your question.  It's not clear what "data conflict" actually means or how it is possible without seeing the actual code that leads to the issue.  The recipes page, the fetch for recipes, the pagination, your use of your recipe store state and actions, etc.  It would be good to review [How to create an MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) then update your question with the relevant details.